# What is the best way to initialize character stats?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a character with a NavMeshAgent

I have a Movement MonoBehaviour attached to that same object.

Say I want to initialize the movement speed. Should I do it in the NavMeshAgent in inspector or make a serialized field in the Movement script that assigns it to the agent during initialization, since move speed is related to the Movement script.

Or maybe there's another way to do it that i'm missing? Was wondering what is the best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your data where it belongs.

NavMeshAgent consumes your 'speed' as input, its not his job to store it.

Movement script makes more sense, or even better a PlayerConfig:ScriptableObject to set the initial value.

But definitivelly keep on Movement script, its job description is on its name. Imagine the player now have a buff or a curse that make it faster/slower, you would change the Movement script for it (and the movement will update the NavMeshAgent).